# MySQL Server keeps "going away" in PHP script

Tags: php, mysql, linux

I have a script that is attempting to log some data (usually around 200-300kb at a time).  It has been running just fine for quite some time.  I do not know of any configuration changes made to either the MySQL server or the PHP on the processing server.  Yesterday the following code block started misbehaving.  Two days ago the "$sqlBucket" query worked just fine.  Now, it fails and the mysql_error returns "MySQL server has gone away".  I added the debugging in the first if block and it outputs:

```
The Link Is Down
Link still down
```

The code:

```
if (!mysql_ping($conn))  {
   echo "The Link Is Down!\n";
   mysql_close($conn);
   if (!($conn = mysql_connect($hostname,$username,$password))) echo "Fail " . $mysql_error() . "\n";
   mysql_select_db($db,$conn);
   if (!mysql_ping($conn)) echo "Link still down\n";
}
if (!mysql_query($sqlBucket, $conn)) {
    echo "Could not execute: {$sqlBucket}" . mysql_error() . "\n";
}
```

If anyone has any thoughts on something to check, debug, reconfigure, etc I have run out of ideas.
Thanks.

EDIT:  Extra info

The script executes and fails in ~3 seconds.

The wait_timeout value on the MySQL server is 28800.

I am able to send the queries successfully through the command line.

I added a check on the mysql_connect function and it is reporting success (at least I am not getting a "Fail" in the output).

Comment: how long (secounds) is it taking? had that issue with slow\long scripts and a temperamental db server

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gone-away.html

Comment: Did you try `mysql_close($conn);` before reconnecting?

Comment: @Dagon - now that it is failing it executes for ~3 seconds

Comment: @Matt - yeah...I've read it.  It didn't help.

Comment: @inhan - I have now.  Unfortunately, no difference.

Comment: latency? I had this same problem when we were running multiple queries from the same php scripts. The connection was timing out. So even though our queries were fast, the mysql server would go away because our php script would take a few seconds to parse the results, then try to do another query... I raised the wait_timeout and it solved the problem. I will also get "mysql has gone away" when I'm debugging my php scripts and the debugger sits for a while and then I try to do another code step. Does your script process multiple queries?

Comment: It does process multiple queries.  This is just the first of them.  I would understand a timeout situation if I wasn't reconnecting to the database which would essentially be milliseconds prior to the query being executed.

Comment: monitor the connections with mysql workbench. That helped me find my problem when our server kept going away. I would run "top" on the server to and watch the mysql process while looking at mysql workbench  to see the connections when running our scripts

Answer (score 1):

Look at the table structures and indexes - as the table grows, it can take longer to write data. 200-300 kB sounds a fair bit of data, and that will accumulate quickly (1 MB every 3-4 updates).

Also, enable your MySQL [slow query log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/slow-query-log.html) to see exactly where the slowness is entering your system.

Comment: I should have been more specific, the table that this is initially failing on is a lookup table that only is less than 1kb per row and is only ~500Mb in size currently.  I do have some 100+Gb tables but I'm not even getting to those before the errors kick in.
I do have the slow query log running and it is not showing anything connected with this script.

Answer (score 0):

Post-Mortem:

Apparently the solution to this one had very little to do with the error code I was receiving.  As it turned out I had, in an attempt to free up some room, removed a superfluous table.  Well, what I didn't realise is that another developer had a trigger that was populating this table.  The trigger was called for inserts on the table that I was involved in the query in a block below the code block I referenced in the original question.  What I noticed is that the code executed fine the first time and then was failing after that.  What was happening was that the trigger error was somehow killing the connection to the server.  After dropping the trigger the script started running just fine.

I am still unsure why redoing the connection wasn't allowing it to proceed and act like it would during the first iteration.